# Aparece la referencia (números) y no los string (texto)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, string, textview

Mi problema es que puse en mi archivo String.xml unos textos y los pase a mi código de esta forma:

```
public String[] slide_descs = {

        String.valueOf(R.string.texto_añade),
        String.valueOf(R.string.texto_buscador),
        String.valueOf(R.string.texto_oscuro),
};
```

Pero cuando lo corro en el simulador me aparece de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde ustedes ven los números es donde debería aparecerme el texto, espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Este es el xml del Layout que se ve en la imagen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slide_image"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_orig" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/slide_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/añade_contenido"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/slide_heading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="@string/texto_añade" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: podrias poner el xml de ese layout ?

Comment: Ya edite la publicación ahí esta el xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuándo pones R.string.texto_buscador estás indicando un número entero que luego conviertes a tipo String y lo añades a tu TextView. Este número entero corresponde al id guardado en el archivo R, por eso te está mostrando el id de los strings en tu aplicación.

Tienes dos opciones, la primera sería indicarlo en el layout correspondiente, utilizando el atributo android:text="@string/nombre_string"

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitulo"
            style="@style/titulos"
            android:text="@string/titulo" />
```

La segunda forma para añadirlo programaticamente sería como lo haces pero sin hacer un cast, al menos a mi me funciona correctamente. Si lo casteas con String.valueOf estás haciendo que el número entero se convierta en un string y entonces añada ese texto, si no lo casteas entonces busca la referencia del ID y pone el texto en cuestión que extrae del archivo String.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvPrueba);
tv.setText (R.string.prueba);
```

Según los comentarios que has dejado te dejo otra posible solución, cambia el array de Strings y crea un array de enteros (int), entonces almacenas las referencias y luego haces los setText con esas referencias:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvPrueba1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvPrueba2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvPrueba3);

    int [] idStrings =
    {
            R.string.prueba,
            R.string.prueba2,
            R.string.prueba3
    };

    tv.setText (idStrings[0]);
    tv2.setText (idStrings[1]);
    tv3.setText (idStrings[2]);
```

Según tu comentario puedes cambiarlo de esta manera en ver de 0,1,2 usas position claro. Aún que estaría bien que añadieras un poco más de código a tu pregunta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Aun no pude lograrlo, te cuento que solo tengo un TextView para 3 textos diferentes y dependen de su posición para saber cual texto se muestra, ejemplo lo de mi foto es la primera pantalla con su respectivo texto pero deslizas y se cambia a otra pantalla y aparece otro texto el cual le corresponde aquí te muestro el código del textview en relación con el que puse en mi publicación: `TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading); slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);`

Comment: Te edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora me aparecen los textos correctamente!!! saludos y feliz año nuevo